# Masking an image with CSS doesn't work on chrome

Tags: html, css

**Demo:**

```css
.mask1 {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(feather.png);
  mask-image: url(feather.png);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="mask1">
  <img src="camp nou.jpg" alt="barcelona" width="600" height="400">
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need An image with a mask layer, but the maske-image property is not supporting  in  chrome.i need a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

```
&lt;div id="masked"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

#masked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12676/star.svg);
}


http://felixjely.fr/projet/DGN1/film-couloir/img/piranese/mask-01.jpg
```